# Is it possible to convert a string array to a string literal union type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to convert this:

```
  const readonlyArray: readonly ['a', 'b', 'c'] = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
  type DesiredType = typeof readonlyArray[number];
```

to something like:

```
  const array = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // this will come dynamically and sometimes it will be ['a', 'e', 'f']
  const readonlyArray = array as const;
  type DesiredType = typeof readonlyArray[number];
```

I think this is not possible, but do you have a similar solution that will do the same work?

---

Here is the simplified version of the real world problem:

I have a React component with 2 props - `status: 'a' | 'b'`, `renamedPropB?: string` and if you change the `renamedPropB` from `undefined` to let's say `'Z'` the type of the `status` should become `'a' | 'Z'` instead of the original `'a' | 'b'`.

And the idea is to have the string literals in the union in an string array so it will be dynamic and easier to change the `'b'` to `'Z'` as well as to add more or remove existing string literals from the union.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply `as const` after the fact.  It has to be done at the time the array or object is created.

If the array is coming from an external source then I believe the answer is no, this can't be done.  You can always get the type of the elements in the array, but if the array is created as `string[]` then the element type will be `string`, not the literal values.